# Inner Product and unitary equivalence

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Suppose that $K$ is a Hilbert space and $A$, $B$ are two unitary operators on $K$ such that

$$P_HAy=-P_HBy, y\in K,$$

for some subspace $H$ of $K$. Consider the following subspaces of $K$:

$$H'=\{P_{H^\perp}Ax:~x\in H\},~H''=\{P_{H^\perp}Bx:~x\in H\}.$$

Suppose that $\psi:H'\to H''$, defined by

$$\psi(P_{H^\perp}Ax)=P_{H^\perp}Bx$$

is unitary.

Let $M$ be any positive operator on $H$. It is also given that

$$\|P_{H^\perp}Ax\|^2=\|P_{H^\perp}Bx\|^2=\|Mx\|^2, x\in H.$$

From this can we conclude that $\langle P_{H^\perp}Ax, P_{H^\perp}Bx\rangle = \|Mx\|^2$?

Comment: The last two conditions would imply that $P_{H^\perp}Ax=P_{H^\perp}Bx$ for $x\in H.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Can you please explain in detail. Thank you.

Comment: If $\|u\|=\|v\|$ and $\langle u, v\rangle=\|u\|\,\|v\|$ then $u=v.$ In your case $u=P_{H^\perp}Ax$ and $v=P_{H^\perp}Bx,$ $x\in H.$

Comment: The penultimate equality in your post gives $\|u\|=\|v\|=\|Mx\|$ The last equality, that you were asking for, amounts to  $\langle u, v\rangle =\|Mx\|^2=\|u\|\,\|v\|.$